# How to grep a word inside xml files in a folder

Tags: regex, linux, grep, recursive-query

I know I can use grep to find a word in all the files present in a folder like this

```
grep -rn core .
```

But my current directory has many sub-directories and I just want to **search in all xml files present in the current directory and its all sub directories**. How can I do that ?

I tried this

```
grep -rn core *.xml // Does not work
```

But it searches for xml files present in the current directory only. It does not do it recursively.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try the `--include` option

```
grep -R --include="*.xml" "pattern" /path/to/dir
```

Reference: [Grep Include Only *.txt File Pattern When Running Recursive Mode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-grep-include-file-pattern-recursive-example/)

Answer (score 3):

I use this often:

```
grep 'pattern' /path/to/dir/**/*.xml
```

#### EDIT:

with zsh

Comment: why is this so bad that get the `-1`?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `**` gives errors (no such file or directory)

Comment: @ChrisMaes I am with zsh.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find`:

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.xml' -exec grep -H 'pattern' {} \;
```