# Finding the number of xml files having a particular word in a directory

Tags: regex, xml, linux, grep

I read [Chris Maes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428078/how-to-grep-a-word-inside-xml-files-in-a-folder) answer on how to a grep for a particular word in any file/files contained in a directory, and it worked.

But, what is the way of finding the names of the files and the total number of files containing that word ?

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: this is quite broad. We cannot correct you because you did not show any attempt. Please [edit] and show them

Comment: `grep -l -R --include="*.xml" "pattern" /path/to/dir`? pipe to `wc -l` to get the count

Comment: I tried it @7171u but it is giving some random numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `--files-with-matches` to the grep command:

```
grep -R --files-with-matches --include="*.xml" "pattern" /path/to/dir
```

If you want the number of matched files you can use pipe the output from the above grep to `wc -l` (or you can also pipe it to `nl`, so each line will be numbered).